# Possible to combine assignment and comparison in an expression?

Tags: rust, control-flow

In C, it's common to assign and compare in a single expression:

```
n = n_init;
do {
    func(n);
} while ((n = n.next) != n_init);
```

As I understand it this can be expressed in Rust as:

```
n = n_init;
loop {
    func(n);
    n = n.next;
    if n == n_init {
        break;
    }
}
```

Which works the same as the C version (assuming the body of the loop doesn't use `continue`).

Is there a more terse way to express this in Rust, or is the example above ideal?

For the purposes of this question, assume ownership or satisfying the borrow checker isn't an issue. It's up to developer to satisfy these requirements.

For example, as an integer:

```
n = n_init;
loop {
    func(&vec[n]);
    n = vec[n].next;
    if n == n_init {
        break;
    }
}
```

This may seem obvious that the Rust example is idiomatic Rust - however I'm looking to move quite a lot of this style of loop to Rust, I'm interested to know if there is some better/different way to express it.

Comment: I'd consider wrapping the pattern into an iterator, so you'd do something like: `for n in some_iter(n_init) { func(n) }`

Comment: Could you please post COMPLETE examples. Each time you post a snippet we have to guess at what the involved types could be. Are they `Copy`? Do they have ownership over something? We don't know! we don't know!

Comment: @Matthieu M am interested in what kinds of flow control can be expressed, I rather not include exact types in my question since it distracts from other aspects, and that part I rather manage myself.

Comment: This question is marked to close as: `Questions seeking debugging help`, can someone explain why? - Its intended to be a question about how to express flow control. There are no bugs to debug here.

Comment: @ideasman42: The problem is that this is making the job of *answerers* much harder, because *ownership* is a core idea of Rust, and thus answers differ depending on whether you use affine types, borrows, or `Copy` types. It's like your last question when you added *after the fact* the condition that `test()` answered `false` the first time... had this been encoded in the code from the beginning I could have known my answer did not fit. But since I could not *read your mind*, I provided an answer that fit and you *after* changed the question so it would not fit any longer. So.. COMPLETE please.

Comment: @Matthieu M. For this question just assume borrow checker isn't raising issues (noted in question, they could be int's for example).

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way to represent iteration in Rust is to use an `Iterator`. Thus you would implement an iterator that does the `n = n.next` and then use a `for` loop to iterate over the iterator.

```
struct MyIter<'a> {
    pos: &'a MyData,
    start: &'a MyData,
}
impl<'a> Iterator for MyIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a MyData;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a MyData> {
        if self.pos as *const _ == self.start as *const _ {
            None
        } else {
            let pos = self.pos;
            self.pos = self.pos.next;
            Some(pos)
        }
    }
}
```

it is left as an exercise to the reader to adapt this iterator to be able to start from the first element instead of starting from the second.

Answer (score 2):

Rust supports pattern matching in `if` and `while`:

- instead of having a boolean condition, the test is considered successful if the pattern matches
- as part of pattern matching, you bind the values matched to names

Thus, if instead of having a boolean condition you were building an `Option`...

```
fn check(next: *mut Node, init: *mut Node) -> Option<*mut Node>;

let mut n = n_init;
loop {
    func(n);
    if let Some(x) = check(n.next, n_init) {
        n = x;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if you can use an `Iterator` instead you'll be much more idiomatic.

Comment: While interesting (and probably a good solution in some cases), this reads like a round-about and indirect answer which makes the flow control less clear then simply breaking once the initial value is reached.

Comment: @ideasman42: Fully agreed, but if you want assignment in a condition, that is the only pattern I can think of (and I would NOT encourage its use).

Answer (score 0):

An assignment in Rust returns the empty tuple. If you are fine with non-idiomatic code you can compare the assignment-result with such an empty tuple and use a logical conjunction to chain your actual loop condition.

```
let mut current = 3;
let mut parent;

while (parent = get_parent(current)) == () && parent != current {
    println!("currently {}, parent is {}", current, parent);
    current = parent;
}

// example function
fn get_parent(x: usize) -> usize {
    if x > 0 { x - 1 } else { x }
}

// currently 3, parent is 2
// currently 2, parent is 1
// currently 1, parent is 0
```

> This has the disadvantage that entering the loop needs to run logic (which you can avoid with C's `do {..} while()`; style loops).

You can use this approach inside a do-while macro, but readability isn't that great and at that point a refactoring might be preferable. In any case, this is how it could look:

```
do_it!({
    println!("{}", n);
} while (n = n + 1) == () && n < 4);
```

This is the code for the macro:

```
macro_rules! do_it {
    ($b: block while $e:expr) => {
        loop {
            $b
            if !($e) { break };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that entering the loop needs to run logic (which you can avoid with C's `do {..} while();` style loops).

Comment: I have updated the answer with a do..while example, but at this point you're pretty far off the beaten track.

Comment: The problem with this is a `continue` statement in `$b` will skip the final break.

Comment: Yes, as per your question this is assuming there is no continue in the block. If you wanted to avoid that as well you could probably wrap $b inside a fixed single or two iteration loop and try to tell whether a continue or break was used based on additional assignments you make inside that loop.