# Is it possible to declare a variable in the conditional of an if expression in Rust?

Tags: if-statement, rust, scope, variable-declaration

In Go, we can declare a variable inside the conditional of an `if` expression. This variable will be valid inside the `if` scope, and not outside of it. For example:

```golang
func main() {
    if n := 4; n != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%d is not zero", n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d is zero", n)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d", n) // error, n doesn't exist here!
}
```

Is there a similar syntax in Rust?

Comment: See also [Possible to combine assignment and comparison in an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40397672/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust does have [`if let` expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html):

```rust
if let n = 4 {}

println!("{}", n); // error: cannot find value `n` in this scope
```

These are primarily used for pattern matching:

```rust
let optional_num = Some(1);

if let Some(num) = optional_num {
    println!("optional_num contained", num);
} else {
    println!("optional_num was None");
}
```

There is an RFC for [if let chains](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2497-if-let-chains.md) that would allow for something like this:

```rust
if let n = 4 && n != 0 {
    println!("{} is not zero", n);
}

println!("{}", n); // error, n doesn't exist here!
```

However, the variables declared in `if let` chains are scoped only to the `if` statement, not the `else`, so your example would not be possible:

```rust
if let n = 4 && n != 0 {
    println!("{} is not zero", n);
} else {
    println!("{}", n); // error, n doesn't exist here! 
}
```

Comment: I don't think your assertions as to the behaviour of `if let` chains is correct, it doesn't match the desugaring provided in the RFC, and doesn't make much sense (as it straight would not work if the pattern were failible and failed).

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I feel like what you're trying to do in your code more closely aligns with a match statement. Something like this:

```
match 4 {
    n @ 0 => {
        println!("{} is zero", n);
    },
    
    n => {
        println!("{} is not zero", n);
    }
}
```

Or, more generically, if you want to test some arbitrary boolean expression based on n:

```
match some_expression {
    n if some_boolean_function(n) => {
        println!("{} meets the requirements", n);
    },
    
    n => {
        println!("{} does not meet the requirements", n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a new scope using curly braces:

```rust
fn main() {
    {
        let n = 4;
        if n != 0 {
            println!("{} is not zero", n);
        } else {
            println!("{} is zero", n);
        }
    }
    
    println!("{}", n); // error, n doesn't exist here!
}
```

If you felt strongly enough about it, you could wrap that in a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! thing {
    ($($s:stmt);+ , $e:expr) => {{
        $($s)+
        $e
    }};
}

fn main() {
    thing!(let n = 4, if n != 0 {
        println!("{} is not zero", n);
    } else {
        println!("{} is zero", n);
    });
    
    println!("{}", n); // error, n doesn't exist here!
}
```